# How to serialize pagination objects in django-rest-framework from a haystack search?

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I currently have the following paginated results using the following view and serializer:

**views.py**

```
class DotaSearchViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = DotaSearchSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        results = EmptySearchQuerySet()

        if request.GET.get('q') is not None:
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
            paginator = Paginator(sqs, 10)

            page = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')
            try:
                results = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                results = paginator.page(1)
            except InvalidPage:
                results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return results
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DotaSearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    quality = serializers.CharField()
    type = serializers.CharField()
    rarity = serializers.CharField()
    hero = serializers.CharField()
    image = serializers.CharField()
    desc = serializers.CharField()

class PaginatedDotaSearchItemsSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):

    """
    Serializes page objects of results querysets.
    """
    start_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_start_index')
    end_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_end_index')
    num_pages = serializers.Field(source='paginator.num_pages')

    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = DotaSearchSerializer

    def get_start_index(self, page):
        return page.start_index()

    def get_end_index(self, page):
        return page.end_index()

    def get_curr_page(self, page):
        return page.number
```

Now I am not sure if my pagination serializer is set up correctly, but how do I get it to serialise the pagination object within my results query.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well I wish I read the documentation in more detail, I just found out the that ListModelMixin comes with a pagination attribute as well as an attribute to define a custom pagination serializer.

```
class DotaSearchViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = DotaSearchSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    paginate_by = 10
    pagination_serializer_class = PaginatedDotaSearchItemsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        sqs = EmptySearchQuerySet()

        if request.GET.get('q') is not None:
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)

        return sqs

class PaginatedDotaSearchItemsSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):

    """
    Serializes page objects of results querysets.
    """
    start_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_start_index')
    end_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_end_index')
    num_pages = serializers.Field(source='paginator.num_pages')
    current_page = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_curr_page')

    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = DotaSearchSerializer

    def get_start_index(self, page):
        return page.start_index()

    def get_end_index(self, page):
        return page.end_index()

    def get_curr_page(self, page):
        return page.number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `source='XXXXXX'` then you should do like this;

```
serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='paginator.num_pages')
```